# How do I connect my bluetooth Jaybird Bluebuds X to my Sony VAIO?

Tags: bluetooth, vaio, sony, bluetooth-speaker

I'm using Ubuntu 14.10 on my Sony VAIO VPCCW290X. I turn Bluetooth on and click "set up new device" and set my Jaybird Bluebuds X to pairing mode. after about 4 seconds, the buds stop trying to pair. My VAIO can detect and pair with my iPhone 5S (I just did this to test the bluetooth).

Are there any additional drivers I need to install? Any other programs that might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I feel really stupid now. To put the Bluebuds into proper pairing mode, you have to have them off, then hold the power button until it turns on, AND starts pairing. Then it connects no problem. You might also have to go into the system sound settings and change the mode from Telephony Duplex to High Fidelity Playback. The volume controls on the Bluebuds work too and the microphone is detected (I haven't tried it).

Comment: I know for a fact the microphone works 'cause I use them for that with SKype on my Ubuntu.  :P